# How to remove role = "link" attribute from specific li in a ul

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accessibility

In wordpress I have a menu with 6 items in it - item 1 and item 4 are not linked to pages and act as headings, however by default they are tagged for accessibility with role="link" the same as the other items.

How can I remove the role attribute of those 2 specific li?

Its a UL list where most of the items have a url associated with them, but 2 of the items do not. The ones that dont arent linking anywhere and so they just act as headings for the other list items.

e.g

```
    <ul>
    <li>Heading 1<a></a><li>
    <li>Link Item 1<a>some link path</a><li>
    <li>Link Item 2<a>some link path</a><li>
    <li>Link Item 3<a>some link path</a><li>
    <li>Heading 2<a></a><li>
    <li>Link Item 4<a>some link path</a><li>
    <li>Link Item 5<a>some link path</a><li>`
```

By default all of them have aria-role=link but that's incorrect for li 1 and 4 so I want to remove that role from them.

```
    <li class="emphasize-menu et_pb_menu_page_id-42615 menu-item 
    menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item- 
    42615"><a role="link">CUSTOMERS</a></li>
```

I have tried the following to pick the li item by class and then remove the attribute but with no success.

`jQuery(function($){ $('.menu-item-42615').removeAttribute("role"); });`

Comment: You will need to provide much more information. What module is this menu generated by? How is it possible that there are headings in a menu? Are you talking about `h1` etc? Did you overwrite the template? Are there any plugins involved?

Comment: I updated the op to add in an example

Comment: I don't know anything deep about wordpress so I don't know how that `<ul>` is created, but ... do you _have to_ put that empty `<a></a>` in 1 and 4?  Could those instead be like `<li><h1>Heading 1</h1></li>`?

Comment: Unfortunately its just within a menu so the UL and LI elements are already setup in the html behind it and the a href already wrapped around the li so I can't remove it - which is why I was hoping to target it in jquery and remove the role that way.

Comment: You are right, only  `a[href]` implicity has role `link`, and that’s for a good reason. But you are still not sharing much information. How did these items end up as headings? Which theme are you using? Again, are there plugins involved? I tried on the Wordpress Playground, and you cannot add Headings to a menu.

Comment: @StephenP, there should only be ONE h1 on a site for the page’s title. Inside a menu, if there are headings, their sub items should be in their own list item group, which is not the case in the above example.

Comment: @Andy, I strongly disagree with that. The page's title and the top level heading don't even have to be the same. With the `<section>` and `<article>` tags it is perfectly reasonable to have an h1 in each section or each article.  Also, I was just using h1 as an example — you would use an appropriate `<h(n)>` depending where in the content hierarchy OP's list exists, but since they show "Heading 1" in their example I used h1 in my example.

Comment: [h1 as a generic section headline was dropped from the standard a while ago](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html). MDN reads “[Avoid using multiple `<h1>` elements on one page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#avoid_using_multiple_h1_elements_on_one_page)”

Comment: @Andy - thanks for the links. I find this quote interesting: "it was revoked not because ... it was a bad idea, but because of screen readers not implementing it correctly" So "use only 1 h1" is a factor for a11y. MDN says: "While using multiple h1 elements on one page is allowed by the HTML standard this is not considered a best practice" saying it *does* conform to standard (but is discouraged). In the spec 4.3.11 it says "at least a single heading within the outline should have a heading level of 1" and "A document can contain multiple top-level headings". Not *only* one, *at least* one.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that you tried is not working because the `<li>` does not have any role assigned. It’s the `<a>` child which has the role.

Additionally, you should not work with IDs, which would only work for one specific menu item. You should apply the workaround more widely to all heading menu items.

```
jQuery(function($){ $('.menu-item a[role=link]').removeAttribute("role"); });

// or, without hardening the absurd dependence on jQuery even more
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item a[role=link]').forEach(a => a.removeAttribute('role');
```

We can completely ignore whether a `href` attribute is present, because [an `a` element with `href` already has the `link` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-a).

This is a workaround, because manipulating DOM after it has been rendered is bad for performance, and unstable.

A real fix would be to make sure the correct, cache-able HTML is delivered by the back-end. But to suggest such a solution, one would need to know the used theme, involved plugins and overwrites in a monolithic CMS like Wordpress.

### Remaining accessibility issues

Be aware that even if this workaround fixes the role issue, the structure is not sufficiently representing the grouping, and you might fail [WCAG Success Criterion 1.3.1: Info and Relationships](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships.html)

Here is an example that makes the grouping-relationship machine-readable:

```
<ul>
  <li>Heading 1<a></a>
    <ul>
      <li>Link Item 1<a>some link path</a><li>
      <li>Link Item 2<a>some link path</a><li>
      <li>Link Item 3<a>some link path</a><li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Heading 2<a></a>
    <ul>
      <li>Link Item 4<a>some link path</a><li>
      <li>Link Item 5<a>some link path</a><li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They are li items in a custom menu without a link or ahref applied to them - so the other items in the list are given a link and those 2 are not. However as they sit inside a menu all of them are being treated as li items with the role link applied to them (whether an ahref is supplied or not).

Comment: The code in your question does not reflect that: `<a role="link">CUSTOMERS</a>`.